# Static for cycle

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, c++-amp

I am writing templated short vector and small matrix classes, that are not restricted to having 2-3-4 elements, but can have an arbitrary number of elements.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class ShortVector
{
public:

    ...

    template <size_t I> T& get() { return m_data[I]; }
    template <size_t I> const T& get() const { return m_data[I]; }

private:

    T m_data[N];
};
```

I want to have the access interface be static, so that I can specialize the class to use built-in vector registers for the supported sizes of the class. (May them be AVX, C++AMP or OpenCL vectors.) Problem is that writing ALL the desirable operators for this class (unary-, +, -, *, /, dot, length, ...) requires an awful lot of template recursion, and I haven't even gotten to implement matrix-vector and matrix-matrix multiplication, where I will need nested recursion.

Right now I have non-member friend operators and a private member class with various static functions such as

```
template <size_t I, typename T1, typename T2> struct Helpers
{
    static void add(ShortVector& dst, const ShortVector<T1, N>& lhs, const ShortVector<T2, N>& rhs)
    {
        dst.get<I>() = lhs.get<I>() + rhs.get<I>();
        Helpers<I - 1, T1, T2>::add(dst, lhs, rhs);
    }

    ...
};
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Helpers < 0, T1, T2 >
{
    static void add(ShortVector& dst, const ShortVector<T1, N>& lhs, const ShortVector<T2, N>& rhs)
    {
        dst.get<0>() = lhs.get<0>() + rhs.get<0>();
    }

    ...
};
```

Writing static functions and specializations like this for all operators just feels wrong. Writing the more complex operations in this manner is highly error prone. What I'm looking for is something like

```
static_for< /*Whatever's needed to define something like a run-time for cycle*/, template <size_t I, typename... Args> class Functor>();
```

Or practically anything that let's me omit the majority of this boilerplate code. I have started writing such a class, but I could not get it to compile with a reasonable specialization. I feel I still lack the skill to write such a class (or function). I have looked at other libs such as Boost MPL, but have not fully committed to using it. I have also looked at std::index_sequence which might also prove useful.

While the std::index_sequence seems like the most portable solution, it has a major flaw I am reluctant to look over. Ultimately these classes must be [SYCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/sycl) compatible, meaning I am restricted to using C++11, including template metaprogramming techniques. std::integer_sequence is a C++14 STL library addition, and while this restriction of language standard only matters in terms of language features, nothing prevents the STL implementer to use C++14 language features while implementing a C++14 STL feature, therefore using C++14 STL features might not be portable.

I am open to suggestions, or even solutions.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/BESRthrd) is what I'v come up so far. This is the header of Template Metaprogramming tricks I started to collect, and the for loop would be next in line. The helper needs a functor which has the running index as it's first parameter, and accepts various predicates. It would keep instantiating the functor as long as the predicate for the next iteration holds true. It would be possible to have the running index increment by any number, be multiplied by a number, etc.

Comment: hint: nobody says "for cycle". It's a _loop_ construct

Comment: You can make your `helper` class take a function object that actually determines what is computed and then call it with a lambda in the definition of the actual `operator`s

Comment: Check out Eigen, it might save you a lot of work: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: What does this **mean**: "I want to have the access interface be static, so that I can specialize the class to use built-in vector registers for the supported sizes of the class". Exactly what is a "built-in vector register"? And what does the rest mean? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I _think_ OP uses `static` (incorrectly) to mean _using template parameters instead of function arguments_, and wants to specialize operations to use SIMD or GPU operations for compatible array types and lengths.

Comment: Even if that's right, it'd be very useful if OP would show what those specialized cases were, so we could maybe figure how to dispatch them ...

Comment: To be honest, I think you're overthinking this; using a simple for loop with bounds known at compile time will produce very good code with all recent compilers; you are forcing all of these loops to be unrolled, which is not always the best option (modern Intel cpus at least are really good at _short_ loops); You are going down the path of libraries like POOMA and Blitz, which essentially wrote code generators using template expressions. Specializing for SIMD is a separate issue; you may want to have a defaulted SIMD width for your types (defaulted to 1 for the generic scalar implementation).

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, using simple for loops will allow some compilers to auto-vectorize; compiler autovectorization is not a given, and I have seen it do much worse than hand-tuned intrinsics, but with the recursive template approach you are making it extra hard for the compilers to even figure out what you're doing. Recursive templates may also lead to reverse visitation patterns over elements if you get lazy.

Comment: Useless is correct, I intend on specializinh my class to built-in SIMD types. For loops with bounds known at compile-time is not enough. I cannot access an element of a SIMD type with a run-time variable (such as the running index of a for loop), even if the bounds are compile-time constants. The operators I'm trying to implement are standard vector operations, element-wise operations, plus the most common vector operations. About "fair amount of effort", I have spent 2 days coding my static for loop class, but copy+pasting code that is a fair distance from even compiling is bad form IMHO.

Comment: The reason I need to implement these classes myself, is because these are classes that will be used in SYCL and C++AMP code, therefore I need to freely be able to decorate constructors, operators and what not with restrict(amp) decorators and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
template <size_t I, typename Functor, typename = std::make_index_sequence<I>>
struct Apply;

template <size_t I, typename Functor, std::size_t... Indices>
struct Apply<I, Functor, std::index_sequence<Indices...>> :
    private std::tuple<Functor> // For EBO with functors
{
    Apply(Functor f) :  std::tuple<Functor>(f) {}
    Apply() = default;

    template <typename InputRange1, typename InputRange2, typename OutputRange>
    void operator()(OutputRange& dst,
                    const InputRange1& lhs, const InputRange2& rhs) const
    {
        (void)std::initializer_list<int>
        { (dst.get<Indices>() = std::get<0>(*this)(lhs.get<Indices>(),
                                                   rhs.get<Indices>()), 0)... };
    }
};
```

Usage could be

```
Apply<4,std::plus<>>()(dest, lhs, rhs); // Size or functor type 
                                        // can be deduced if desired
```

A (slightly modified) example: [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b46b086074fca4c7).

You could also remove the functor state if it hinders you in any way:

```
template <size_t I, typename Functor, typename = std::make_index_sequence<I>>
struct Apply;

template <size_t I, typename Functor, std::size_t... Indices>
struct Apply<I, Functor, std::index_sequence<Indices...>>
{
    template <typename InputRange1, typename InputRange2, typename OutputRange>
    void operator()(OutputRange& dst,
                    const InputRange1& lhs, const InputRange2& rhs) const
    {
        (void)std::initializer_list<int>
        { (dst.get<Indices>() = Functor()(lhs.get<Indices>(),
                                          rhs.get<Indices>()), 0)... };
    }
};
```

Comment: That's nice. I forgot I could still use `std::plus<>` when I decided to use poly-lambdas for my sample :)

Comment: While this code I'm afraid will not compile in my case (explained in just a bit), it did gave me good ideas. Inheriting from std::tuple<> will render the Apply class AMP-incompatible, as not all member functions of tuple are decorated with restrict(amp). (In fact, none of them are) However the body of operator() does hold some nice ideas: static_cast<void> of std::iniitializer_list<int>{(/*actual work*/)...} I find elegant. Deserves up-vote.

Comment: @Meteorhead The code can easily be modified to work without `tuple`. `tuple` is used merely to efficiently save functors with state. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at Boost Fusion's algorithms.

All that's required is to adapt your type as a Fusion Sequence.

Simple sample: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/659facd4379b656d)**

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    boost::array<int, 4> iv4 { 1,2,3,4 };
    boost::array<double, 4> id4 { .1, .2, .3, .4 };

    auto r = fusion::transform(iv4, id4, [](auto a, auto b) { return a+b; });
    std::cout << r;
}
```

Prints:

```
(1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4)
```

Comment: I am afraid that without an example, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I will leave it for the OP to ask if they also want an example of adapting :-)

Comment: @Angew In general, the OP can _want_ many a thing. Fair effort is a requirement on this site though (honestly, if it had been at all clear to me, what the operations should do, I'd usually have simply implemented it as a demo\)

Comment: What is this intended to be a solution to? I can write out the pairwise item sums of two arrays with much less code. Maybe even using `std::valarray` (never used it, though, so it'd be a first). I guess fundamentally I'm asking, what *question* do you perceive in the OP's apparently random verbiage?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The arrays are his implementation detail, and it happened to be already adapted (thorugh `adapted.hpp`). (I'm not required to defend my ability to see a potential question in there, right. You can downvote questions if you think there is none)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If I only had to code for CPU, I'd ditch C++ as it is and I'd already be swimming in the sea of Rust. But because Rust cannot convey all it's goodness into kernel code just yet, I'm stuck with C++ tempate metaprogramming. std::valarray is pretty much useless btw, and it's internal storage is baked to being host side memory. I need classes that can use device-side storage for their data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

**”**  I am restricted to using C++11, including template metaprogramming techniques. `std::integer_sequence` is a C++14 STL library addition […]

… you can do this with e.g. the g++ compiler:

```
namespace my {
    using std::tuple;
    using std::tuple_cat;

    template< int i >
    struct Number_as_type_ {};

    template< int... values >
    using Int_sequence_ = tuple< Number_as_type_<values>... >;

    template< class Int_seq_a, class Int_seq_b >
    using Concat_ = decltype( tuple_cat( Int_seq_a(), Int_seq_b() ) );

    template< int max_index >
    struct Index_sequence_t_
    {
        using T = Concat_<
            typename Index_sequence_t_<max_index-1>::T, Int_sequence_<max_index>
            >;
    };

    template<>
    struct Index_sequence_t_<0> { using T = Int_sequence_<0>; };

    template< int n_indices >
    using Index_sequence_ = typename Index_sequence_t_<n_indices - 1>::T;
}  // namespace my
```

---

Unfortunately Visual C++ 12.0 (2013) chokes on template argument deduction for the above `Int_sequence_`. Apparently it has to do with erroneously treating a templated `using` as a kind automatically referenced local `typedef` in a class. Anyway, working with that understanding of the [Visual C++ compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1013808/ice-internal-compiler-error-crash-related-to-variadic-templates) I rewrote the above as follows, which appears to work nicely also with Visual C++:

*A version that works better with Visual C++ 12.0*

```
namespace my {
    using std::tuple;
    using std::tuple_cat;

    template< int i >
    struct Number_as_type_ {};

    template< int... values >
    struct Int_sequence_
    {
        using As_tuple = tuple< Number_as_type_<values>... >;
    };

    template< int... values >
    auto int_seq_from( tuple< Number_as_type_<values>... > )
        -> Int_sequence_< values... >;

    template< class Int_seq_a, class Int_seq_b >
    using Concat_ = decltype(
        int_seq_from( tuple_cat(
            typename Int_seq_a::As_tuple(), typename Int_seq_b::As_tuple()
            ) )
        );

    template< int n_indices >
    struct Index_sequence_t_
    {
        using T = Concat_<
            typename Index_sequence_t_<n_indices-1>::T, Int_sequence_<n_indices-1>
            >;
    };

    template<>
    struct Index_sequence_t_<1> { using T = Int_sequence_<0>; };

    template< int n_indices >
    using Index_sequence_ = typename Index_sequence_t_<n_indices>::T;
}  // namespace my
```

---

With the above C++11-based support available, a general **compile time indexing `for` loop**, or, if you will, template-based loop unrolling, can be implemented in C++11, so that code like this can be written:

```
template< int i >
struct Add_
{
    void operator()( int sum[], int const a[], int const b[] ) const
    {
        sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    int sum[5];
    int const a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int const b[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};

    my::for_each_index<5, Add_>( sum, a, b );

    for( int x: sum ) { cout << x << ' '; } cout << endl;
}
```

Do note, however, that while this may *appear* to be the next best thing since sliced pizza, I suspect that any reasonably good compiler will do loop unrolling optimizations as a matter of course, i.e. that there is not necessarily any advantage to be gained from introducing this bit of extra complexity.

As always with respect to optimizations, do **MEASURE**.

---

This design does total loop unrolling, that is, instead of *n* executions of a loop body with varying index you get *n* instances of the loop body with different index values. It's not necessarily the best approach, e.g. since larger code has less chance of fitting in a cache (repeat: for optimizations always *measure*), and for parallelism you may have special requirements. You can check out “Duff’s device” for a technique for more limited loop unrolling.

```
namespace my {
    using std::forward;
    using std::initializer_list;

    template< class Type >
    void evaluate( initializer_list< Type > const& ) {}

    namespace impl {
        template< template <int> class Functor_, class... Args >
        struct Call_with_numbers_
        {
            template<  int... numbers >
            void operator()( Int_sequence_<numbers...> const&, Args&&... args ) const
            {
                evaluate( {(Functor_<numbers>()( args... ), 0)...} );
            }
        };
    }  // namespace impl

    template< int n, template<int> class Functor_, class... Args >
    void for_each_index( Args&&... args )
    {
        using Seq = Index_sequence_<n>;
        Seq s;
        impl::Call_with_numbers_< Functor_, Args... >()( s, forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
}  // namespace my
```

Disclaimer: coded up late at night, so not necessarily very perfect! :-/